# MSGraph API unarchive Team and restore Group don't work

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

There is a bug in MSTeams (I think) when you delete a group in Azure the Team in MSTeams is still available. So I archive it before I delete the Group.

Now I want to unarchive it and restore the group. None of these calls working...

```
graphApplicationClient.teams({teamId}).unarchive().buildRequest().post();
```

Error:

```
    Apr. 24, 2020 5:01:55 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFORMATION: Starting to send request, URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/microsoft.graph.unarchive
Apr. 24, 2020 5:01:55 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFORMATION: Request Method POST
Apr. 24, 2020 5:01:55 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SCHWERWIEGEND: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 204Error during http request
Apr. 24, 2020 5:01:55 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SCHWERWIEGEND: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:421)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:204)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:306)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.TeamUnarchiveRequest.post(TeamUnarchiveRequest.java:62)
    at MSTeamsService.main(MSTeamsService.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1770)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1134)
    at okhttp3.MediaType.get(MediaType.java:53)
    at okhttp3.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:106)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider$3.contentType(CoreHttpProvider.java:346)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:53)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.TelemetryHandler.intercept(TelemetryHandler.java:35)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RedirectHandler.intercept(RedirectHandler.java:123)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:140)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:31)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:355)
    ... 5 more
```

And the other call:

```
     graphApplicationClient.directory().deletedItems({team/groupId}).restore().buildRequest().post();
```

ERROR:

```
    Apr. 24, 2020 5:04:14 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFORMATION: Starting to send request, URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/{team/groupId}/microsoft.graph.restore
Apr. 24, 2020 5:04:14 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFORMATION: Request Method POST
Apr. 24, 2020 5:04:14 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SCHWERWIEGEND: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 204Error during http request
Apr. 24, 2020 5:04:14 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SCHWERWIEGEND: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:421)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:204)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:306)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.DirectoryObjectRestoreRequest.post(DirectoryObjectRestoreRequest.java:53)
    at MSTeamsService.main(MSTeamsService.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1770)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1134)
    at okhttp3.MediaType.get(MediaType.java:53)
    at okhttp3.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:106)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider$3.contentType(CoreHttpProvider.java:346)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:53)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.TelemetryHandler.intercept(TelemetryHandler.java:35)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RedirectHandler.intercept(RedirectHandler.java:123)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:140)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:31)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:355)
    ... 5 more
```

(SCHWERWIEGEND means FATAL)

If I try these calls in GraphExplorer they working fine..

Can someone help me?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same problem as I. GraphAPI provides a customRequest() function. I use the same token, the same url, the same properties, but using the customRequest.

```
graphApplicationClient.customRequest("/teams/" + pTeamId + "/unarchive").buildRequest().post(new JsonObject());
```

Same solution for restore..

```
graphApplicationClient.customRequest("/directory/deletedItems/" + pTeamId + "/restore").buildRequest().post(new JsonObject()
```

This isn't the right solution for it, because it should work with the normal GraphAPI, that's why I don't mark this as an answer. But it is a workaround for everyone who has the same problem..